# LD_LIBRARY_PATH for Apache cgi script

Tags: apache, cgi, environment-variables, cgi-bin

I built a .CGI in C++. This binary depends on some `boost` shared library and other resources in a specific folder `/usr/local/boost/`. The CGI doesn't execute and in the log I can see the error

```
    error while loading shared libraries: libdxxx: cannot 
    open shared object file: No such file or dire
```

Now, I've read many logs that say that I have to set in `httpd.conf` the following, but still doesn't work.

```
   SetEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/boost:
```

In my config I set this line "as it is" at the end of the config file without being included in any `VirtualHOst or Directory` section.  I tried to insert into the Directory for the cgi-bin but still the same

```
 <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
     AllowOverride None
     Options None
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
     SetEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/boost
 </Directory>
```

I have also tried (see discurrion below) to add a .conf file for ldconfig but it still doesn't work!

```
  #added a file called myconfig.conf conrtaining a line
  /usr/local/boost 

  /etc/ld.conf.d/
  ldconfig (as root)
```

I have also reead that `httpd` inherits the environment variable of the ROOT user that runs it; as I root I call the following to start Apache and LD_LIBRARY_PATH is correctly set but still something is wrong.

```
 /etc/init.d/httpd start
```

I am using Red Hat 6.2.

Comment: in myconfig.conf you have: #/usr/local/boost, "#" removed ?

Comment: I temporary switched to MONGOOSE and all worked immediately in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In our Linux Debian box, we use this:

Create a config file, add string /usr/local/boost in it:

```
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/boost.conf
```

Then run:

```
# ldconfig
```

And finally:

```
# /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

I don't know how to do it in Red Hat.

Comment: Hi Jacouh! Thanks a lot. This will solve the issue but it will automatically change or the library search path for all my applications. Do you know if there is another solution?

Comment: Can you regroup all your personal .so in some reasonnable number of directories and add all them in a config file line per line ?

Comment: I'll try that. Hoping to not have impact on the group of people I am working with. Anyway is it  a solution to my problem AND a gave me thougts about a better planning for folders for the future.

Comment: Have you commented SetEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /opt/ibm/db2/V9.7/lib64 ? or copy all your .so's in /usr/local/lib ?

Comment: Hi jacouh. Yes I did that (and corrected a small typo in my mail)

Comment: Hi Jacouh..at the end I switched to MONGOOSE. It is a binary running on the same shell like a program and it works immediately..not happy of the solution but it does the job.

Comment: Apache is a big and universal server with multiple modules. + All these developpers for help. For a production site, it's better ?

Comment: I'll tell you as soon as we'll use it massively. For now I am not able to do an evaluation. Anycase I agree with you Apache is de facto a standard and I should better understand it.

Comment: Genius !   That was the only thing that worked after trying numerous suggested solutions.  My problem was SSL libraries not getting included in a Python web cgi.  This works for that.